# Use IdentityServer 4 and WS-Federation

Tags: asp.net-core, ws-federation, identityserver4

I realise that .Net Core doesn't support WS-Federation. However I would really like to use IdentityServer 4, which I realise also doesn't support WS-Federation.

However if I have an ASP.Net Core website and I target the full .Net framework, would it then be possible to use WS-Federation with IdentityServer 4? Is there some sort of interface that can be used?

Like if I used the code from `IdentityServer3.WsFederation` how hard would it be to port it to use IdentityServer4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now use WsFederation with IdentityServer4 even if it runs on AspNetCore by using `IdentityServer4.WsFederation`.

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.WsFederation) which add a new `/wsfederation` EndPoint on your IdentityServer4. This EndPoint will allow you access the same features as `IdentityServer3.WsFederation`.

Comment: Yep, the other side of the coin is to be able to use WS-Federation from an ASP.Net Core app, I don't think that is possible yet...

Comment: I'm confused. The project you linked says, "The underlying WS-Federation classes used in this repo are only part of the 'desktop' .NET Framework and are not included in .NET Core." Doesn't that suggest it will work with IndentityServer4, but not if you're running it on .Net Core?

Comment: It will work with IdentityServer4 ASP.NET Core if you follow this [walkthrough](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/identityserver4-ws-federation-and-sharepoint/). But you still have to target the .NET framework for WsFederation

Comment: As I was told in [my issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.WsFederation/issues/6) this sample is about adding an endpoint to use the IdentityServer as a WsFederation-server, but not as an client.

Answer (score 0):

Some functionality like encrypted XML hasn't yet been ported to .Net core. that is needed for WsFederation to work. [Ws-Federation authentication with ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614708/ws-federation-authentication-with-asp-net-core)

Comment: Yes, but I am targeting the full .Net Framework so I have access to those methods.