# Ws-Federation authentication with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, adfs, ws-federation

I am migrating an ASP.NET application to be on ASP.NET Core, but have met a problem of Ws-Federation authentication: there is no [Ws-Federation] (https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation) OWIN middleware available in ASP.NET Core platform.

But I noticed all authentication middleware for ASP.NET Core are now under [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication) namespace, so I searched all packages from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication) and found most of the authentication packages are there, but unfortunately only the *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation* is missing.

So, I would like to know, if the package is missing because it is not implemented yet or any other reason? Alternatively, is there existing ASP.NET Core based authentication middleware for Ws-Federation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not implemented yet, mainly because .NET Core doesn't have the encrypted XML and XML dsig classes needed.

See https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/500

Comment: As of late 2017, "WsFederation preview support is now available for ASP.NET Core 2.0.0." https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1473

Answer (score 3):

I've ported the Katana middleware over to ASP.NET Core. It has a hard dependency on the full .NET Framework since that is the only place the required libraries exist right now.

https://github.com/chrisdrobison/aspnetcore-wsfed

Answer (score 0):

It appears .NET Core 2.1 WS Federation package is now available. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.

More information found at the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.1